# React does not recognize the `activeStyle` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

[can any one solve this type of error:Warning: React does not recognize the `activeStyle` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `activestyle` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
at a
at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41092:5)
at NavLinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41138:21)
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47755:6)
at div
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47755:6)
at nav
at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47755:6)
at Navbar
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42181:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40990:5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsJFY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavLink` Instead of `Link`

Active style prop works only when using NavLink